# File causing player to play 'arbitrary' data

Tags: video, data-recovery, vlc-media-player

I have come across a really weird thing, and I'm asking so that you might be able to help me make sense of the situation - which I believe shouldn't occur.

So... I started downloading a video file through BitComet and after barely 1% downloaded I stopped the download and decided to open the video file.

The video file did open however the video content was of a video file I at one point had, but then deleted. This video has nothing to do with the video file I was downloading.

Curious as to this fact I decided to split the video file into 10 MB parts and opened some of them. One of the files kept showing that deleted video, while some others started playing songs which were also deleted!

... Can anyone explain how this could happen? Can a file contain arbitrary data that instructs the player to read the data from a different location entirely?

**Notes:**

- I am entirely sure that the torrent I was downloading was of a different video
- I reproduced the same result using both VLC and Windows Media Player
- The video file being played was situated on a different logical disk (same physical disk)
- I wiped the empty disk space (using CCleaner) of the logical disk having the video file, and the file did stop playing that video.

Answer (score -1):

When you started the download, BitComet will have allocated the space for the files you were planning to download to space on the hard disk. When you prematurely stopped the download, the space was still allocated, so when the media players tried to open them, they were looking at that pert of the hard drive, which just so happens to be where the old video and songs used to be stored.

Probably.

Comment: Actually that didn't occur to make and I guess it makes sense. I got used to the idea of the data being cleared out when allocated, but I guess that could happen. Would this also work across logical disks though?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I wouldnt have thought so, but if anything has changed about the disks, something might have happened there. I didn't see that part of the question, so my idea might be less likely.

Comment: If this were possible, it'd be considered a quite serious security issue – most filesystems guard against this and either [zero out](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) the allocated areas or at least [pretend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365544(v=vs.85).aspx) they were zeroed out. Same applies to process memory – while in MS-DOS a process could access leftover information; in modern operating systems that's impossible.